# Get value from WP Short code and assign to PHP Variable

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

I am making posts of computer builds. I have a completely separate MYSQL database that I track computer components, assigned to each build. For instance, BuildID = 4 will have "Asus Rampage VI Extreme Motherboard x299", Core i9 7980xe Extreme LGA 2066" as values that come from the following query:

```
"SELECT BCats.Cat, BParts.ItemName, BParts.ItemSKU, BParts.ItemURL, BParts.ItemPrice, BParts.Qty, BParts.ItemPrice*BParts.Qty AS Price 
FROM BParts
INNER JOIN BCats ON BCats.CatNo = BParts.ItemCat
WHERE BParts.BuildNo = 4 AND BParts.SystemNo = 1
ORDER BY BCats.CatNo ASC"
```

I need to take "BParts.BuildNo = 4" and turn it into a variable, such as "BParts.BuildNo = $buildNo". Then, for each customer that builds one of my desks, I can a photo gallery and just insert the shortcode [build] posts the table for all of the parts belonging to build number 4 (see it work at https://badvolf.com/en/declassified-systems-build/

Forgive me, but I am stumped at how to do it. I have searched everywhere, but nothing seems to fit what I am looking for, but I know that it can be done somehow. Here is what I have so far, and it generates the table that you see on the above link:

```
function wp_build_shortcode(){
    $query = "SELECT BCats.Cat, BParts.ItemName, BParts.ItemSKU, BParts.ItemURL, BParts.ItemPrice, BParts.Qty, BParts.ItemPrice*BParts.Qty AS Price
FROM BParts
INNER JOIN BCats ON BCats.CatNo = BParts.ItemCat
WHERE BParts.BuildNo = 4 AND BParts.SystemNo = 1
ORDER BY BCats.CatNo ASC";
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Build Name</title>
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <col width="15%">
    <col width="85%">
    <col width="20%">

    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Total Price</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    if ($result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'], $query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>


            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["Cat"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["ItemName"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["Qty"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["Price"]; ?></td>
            </tr><?php }
    } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

    <?php
}
add_shortcode('build', 'wp_build_shortcode'); 
?>
```

So, how can I do something like [build="4"] and pass that value on to the query? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your function at least one parameter. For Example `wp_build_shortcode($attributes)`. `$attributes` will be an array with the parsed shortcode parameters. In your case `['build' => '4']. Then you can assign it to any local variable:`$buildNo = issest($attributes['build']) ?
 intval($attributes['build']) : 0;`. [You can find more information here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

In WP shortcodes are accessible for very low privileged users (subscribers). Therefore you should treat the parameters as untrusted user input, and protect yourself from SQL injections and other exploits. In your case the `intval` in the above code should be enough, but prepared statements are a better practice.

Comment: I'm not concerned about SQL injection; the database credentials used to connect only has read permissions for the two tables. I have looked at the information, but I am still missing something... Honestly, I have VERY limited experience (none) with arrays, so I am not sure how I am supposed to pull the data.

Comment: function wp_build_shortcode($attributes){
 $buildNo = issest($attributes['build']) ? intval($attributes['build']) : 0;

 $query = "SELECT BCats.Cat, BParts.ItemName, BParts.ItemSKU, BParts.ItemURL, BParts.ItemPrice, BParts.Qty, BParts.ItemPrice*BParts.Qty AS Price
    FROM BParts
    INNER JOIN BCats ON BCats.CatNo = BParts.ItemCat
    WHERE BParts.BuildNo = $buildNo AND BParts.SystemNo = 1
    ORDER BY BCats.CatNo ASC";
    ?>

add_shortcode('build', 'wp_build_shortcode');

It's not working for me.

Comment: I have a typo in `issest`. It should be `isset`. Sorry about that. I hope it is the only mistake.